# Plugin LDAP Authentication 2 In stallation ploblem

Tags: plugins

I didn't understand the 3rd step of Installation procedure of plugin LDAP Authentication 2 http://wordpress.org/plugins/ldap-authentication-2/installation/

Place  in your templates

Where is the templates to place this script????

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin author made a booboo; that's generic installation "filler" text!

By the looks of things (having tried out the plugin), you don't actually need to do anything else. Just activate & configure the settings in the admin area.

Comment: I have activated and configured the plugin but login procedure doesn't change.